# How to hide all the form fields with a <STYLE>

Tags: css

I am trying to hide all form fields by adding them to a `<style>` (#mainContent)..

I am using select2, and I have added the code below, which will show the `<style>`, once select2 has loaded.

```
    $.when(
$("select[class*='select2']" ).select2({
allowClear: true
})
).done(function(){
$('#mainContent').css({'visibility': 'visible'})
});
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide elements I suggest to make a css class and then add the class on the element.

JQuery also has .show() and .hide() - [Example here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_hide_show)

**display:none** means that the tag in question will not appear on the page at all (although you can still interact with it through the dom). There will be no space allocated for it between the other tags.

**visibility:hidden** means that unlike display:none, the tag is not visible, but space is allocated for it on the page. The tag is rendered, it just isn't seen on the page.

```
#mainContent {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

**Extra info**

```
    +--------------------+----------------+-----------------+
    | Property           | occupies space | consumes clicks |
    +--------------------+----------------+-----------------+
    | opacity: 0         |        ✓       |        ✓        |
    +--------------------+----------------+-----------------+
    | visibility: hidden |        ✓       |        ✗        |
    +--------------------+----------------+-----------------+
    | display: none      |        ✗       |        ✗        |
    +--------------------+----------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Thanks @EnzoTrompeneers... The form elements are within this class '.searchandfilter'... So I can hide them with this '.searchandfilter li { visibility: hidden; }' (in custom CSS)... The trouble I am having is changing the visibility state with the jQuery I'm using, see here............. 'window.jQuery.when(
window.jQuery(“select[class*=’select2′]” ).select2({
allowClear: true
})
).done(function(){
window.jQuery(‘.searchandfilter li’).css({‘visibility’: ‘visible’})
});'

Comment: Have a css class .invisible {visiblity: hidden;} then add/remove the class:
by toggle: $("p").toggleClass("invisible"); OR by addClass: $("p").addClass("invisible"); AND by removeClass: $("p").removeClass("invisible");

Comment: Thanks for the link.... I got it working with this 'jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $(".searchandfilter li").hide();'
});

Answer (score 0):

`$('#mainContent').css({'visibility': 'hidden'})` will hide that element from displaying on the browser. [See this for more details](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp). But the width and all other properties for that element will present there.
If you want to hide an element you can use `$("#mainContent").css({'display':'none'})`.
This can be easily accomplished with the jQuery's *[.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)* function. To make that element visible you can use `.show()` function.

> $("#mainContent").hide();

Comment: Thanks @Sukanya Purushothaman... I am only hidding the elements for a brief moment while select2 loads, as soon as that's done I want to change the hidden state to visible.... I am using this jQuery but it doesn't seem to work, I'm not sure if the CSS I added in the child style.css file is overriding it? '.searchandfilter li { visibility: hidden; }'

Comment: Here is the jQuery that changes the visible state back once the select2 has loaded.... 'window.jQuery.when( window.jQuery(“select[class*=’select2′]” ).select2({ allowClear: true }) ).done(function(){ window.jQuery(‘.searchandfilter li’).css({‘visibility’: ‘visible’}) });'

Comment: If you are hiding the element by setting the CSS visibility property to 'hidden' then you should change that to make them 'visible'. I think you are not setting the `visibility: visible;` property to the hidden element.

Comment: Try this `$(".searchandfilter li’).css({'visibility': 'visible'});

Comment: Sorry I get it now... Hide the class before using jQuery... I'll try it now.

Comment: I managed to get it working with this............  'jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $(".searchandfilter li").hide();
});'  ................. Sorry I'm new to jQuery, didn't realise I needed the ready function.